# Is there a way to hide a folder even when "show hidden files" is checked using python?

Tags: python

I've been wanting to make a program that hides a folder that has a lot of my sensitive files on it.  I use python as my main programming language.

I need a way to hide the folder from Windows Explorer, even if the "Show Hidden Files" option is checked. I know how to hide it normally, right-clicking on the folder and checking the "hidden" option, but I need users to not be able to see it at all. I also need to be able to unhide it using the same program.

If anyone knows a solution, please let me know!
Thank you!

Comment: All of the methods available to Python come from the OS. Other than marking a file as hidden, I think marking it as System is the only other option.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact mechanism in Windows, but you could create an encrypted partition or file system in a file, and then only mount as needed. it would be visible when mounted, invisible otherwise.

Comment: @tdelaney I do believe there is a way to do this using CMD, I'll have a look at that, as that may work and be somewhat portable if I needed it on a USB.

Comment: Rather than hide a folder, I think you want to *encrypt* it

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could make a program that **loads your folder into the RAM** on startup while deleting it and re-saving the folder on shutdown, however this would be **very risky when you press "shutdown anyways"**. If a certain condition is met, you could show the folder(e.g. saving it to file system).

**Another Idea** would be to try to remake it as the very infuriating folder in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` which you can only access in command-line

Also if you are able to complete this project, *I would be very interested in using it too*.

Comment: I do think those are possible, however, like you said, the first option is risky. The second option seems, at first glance, to be able to work. But then comes the issue of adding extra files or folders to _that_ folder, as, like you say, is only accessable via CLI. If there was a way to make a secure partition on a drive, on a USB perhaps, and then mount or unmount it via python, that _could_ work.

Comment: Currently working on this project: kind of a "stealthy" approach, as the python file used to hide and show the secured folder is contained on an alternate data stream (look it up, it's used in digital forensics), and that is read from via another python script and then executed.

Answer (score 0):

I have opted for a secured, hidden folder marked as hidden, system reserved and encrypted, and requiring a python script to unlock. Using the attrib DOS command, but it does the trick. I'm also using EFS encryption on the folder, so even if the system and hidden attributes are cleared, people still can't access it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please remove the part that didn't work and only describe what worked in a clear and concise way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a thumb drive anyways, you could have a live install of Linux on it and stash the files on it encrypted accessible by you, root. Another possible method is a filesystem that is loopback mounted and stashed in an unformatted partition (a "small" one) and tar -cvf /dev/sd?? . Tarballs came about from archiving backups on tape decks raw written. Then you's tar -xvf /dev/tape-deck1 to get the files put back. Of course, you encrypt the files you really want private.

Because you need not mount that partition with the raw written tarball, Windows won't recognise it, nor will Linux show it unless you sudo fdisk. In the latter case, the partition is not assigned a filesystem altogether.